# Discord.py - Getting data from SQL file doesn't work

Tags: python, sql, discord.py

So I want my bot to check the database file for a number(0 means off, 1 means on). I have this

```
@client.event
async def on_message_delete(msg):
    
    db = await asqlite.connect("servers.db")
    cursor = await db.cursor()
    await cursor.execute(f"SELECT ENABLE_OR_DISABLE_ON_MSG_DELETE FROM Servers WHERE Guild_ID = {msg.guild.id}")
    result = await cursor.fetchone()
    
    if result == 0:
        return 
    
    if result == 1:
        myembed = discord.Embed(title= "Deleted Message")
        myembed.add_field(name= f'{msg.author} deleted a message(if you want to disable this, just do >disable-del)', value= f'{msg.content}')
        await msg.channel.send(embed=myembed) 
        

    if msg.author.id == msg.author.bot:
        pass
```

But it doesn't work when I set the value in the db file to 1(whereas it should send a message when someone deletes a message). There's no error either.

Comment: <sqlite.Row object at 0x0000023229086A90>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are comparing the row object . this should fix your issue :
result[0]  returns first column in the dataset

```
...
    if result["ENABLE_OR_DISABLE_ON_MSG_DELETE"] == 0:
        return 
    
    if result["ENABLE_OR_DISABLE_ON_MSG_DELETE"] == 1:
        myembed = discord.Embed(title= "Deleted Message")
        ...
```